# is it possible to insert a long sentence to database? from textarea form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, textarea, form-submit

I'm trying to send sentences to the database. its sent but sent empty.

this is the submit form

```
<td align="center" colspan="3">
            <FONT FACE="algerian"><h2>TODAYS TAZKIRAH</FONT>
                <form method="post" id="usrform" action="InsertTazkirah.php"  ><br>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" type="text" name="Tazkirah" form="usrform">
                </textarea><br>
                <input type="submit"><br>
                </form>

        </td>
```

and this is the process to insert to database

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("rock","mido","****","fyp");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Tazkirah (version)
VALUES
('$_POST[version]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }


echo '<script> alert ("done!"); </script>';
include_once("admin.php");
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

in the database table I have `ID` and `version`.
the `ID` `auto_increment` so when I click submit the `ID` been added but the text is not appearing in the database.

thank yoou

Comment: *sidenote:* `<font>` tag has been deprecated; Use CSS instead. Also, use lowercase tags & close your tags properly please.

Comment: *sidenote:* your code is subjected to SQL Injection attack, as you directly allow POST values to be inserted in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Tazkirah (version)
VALUES ('mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST[Tazkirah])')";
```

Comment: @opa.mido : Please accept the answer so that it is easier for others to see the answer

Answer (score 1):

That is because there is no `version` field found in the `<form>` tag.

It should be `$_POST['Tazkirah']` instead of `$_POST[version]`

Since you are using `MySQLi` it is suggested you go for [`Prepared Statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) in MySQLi to ward off SQL Injection attacks.

**Warning : Your PHP Script is prone to SQL Injection Attack. Either filter the parameters or make use of Prepared Statements as suggested in the above link.**

Comment: thanx but its dosent works.. and your warning in mind

Answer (score 0):

You need to change here:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Tazkirah (version)
VALUES
('$_POST['Tazkirah']')";<--- change here
```

[$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) index name of the $_POST  should be similar to the field name.